# The column name start_value was not found in this ResultSet With Hibernate

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate & postgresql with a spring boot application.

First of all i had set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.
When i run the application at first time everything works fine and the tables get created, but later on when i try to run the application again i have this error :  `The column name start_value was not found in this ResultSet`. When changing the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `create` or `none` i no longer face that error but it's not the behavior i want. I want to keep it `update` and without catching that error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, except I was using H2 instead of PostgreSQL. My issue stemmed from the H2 version specified in my pom.xml not matching the actual version of the database.

Check that these two match. That worked for me...

You can use: SELECT VERSION(); to get your PostgreSQL version.